# Angular 12 - Changing value of injected component not updating html

Tags: angular, typescript

I started using dependency injection to inject an `AlertComponent` in all my Component to be able to show alert everywhere but I can't make it work...

AlertComponent :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NgbAlert } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.scss']
})

@Injectable()

export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  private _success = new Subject<string>();

  successMessage = '';
  typeAlert = 'success';

  @ViewChild('selfClosingAlert') selfClosingAlert: NgbAlert;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._success.subscribe(message => this.successMessage = message);
    this._success.pipe(debounceTime(5000)).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.selfClosingAlert) {
        this.selfClosingAlert.close();
      }
    });
  }

  public NewAlert(message: string)
  {
    this.typeAlert = "success";
    this._success.next(message);
  }

  public NewDangerAlert(message: string)
  {
    this.typeAlert = "danger";
    this._success.next(message);
  }

  public NewWarningAlert(message: string)
  {
    this.typeAlert = "warning";
    this._success.next(message);
  }
}
```

His html (I added `<app-alert></app-alert>` in the index.html)

```html
<ngb-alert #selfClosingAlert *ngIf="successMessage" type={{typeAlert}} (closed)="successMessage = ''">
  {{ successMessage }}
</ngb-alert>
```

Example of component that uses it :

```js
import { AlertComponent } from '../alert/alert.component'

@Component({
  providers: [AlertComponent],
  selector: 'app-document-download',
  templateUrl: './document-download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-download.component.scss']
})

export class DocumentDownloadComponent implements OnInit {
  alerte: AlertComponent = null

  constructor(alerte: AlertComponent) {
    this.alerte = alerte;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.alerte.NewWarningAlert("Hello, this is a test.")
  }
}
```

Using the `NewWarningAlert` function works when I call it directly from `AlertComponent` but not from my DocumentDownloadComponent.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't know if it's the best :

In `DocumentDownloadComponent` I changed `alerte: AlertComponent = null` to `@ViewChild(AlertComponent) alerte: AlertComponent;` (no need to instantiate it in constructor anymore).

I also had to add the selector in `DocumentDownloadComponent` html, `<app-alert></app-alert>` in my case.